# Shapefiles not visible in ArcGIS Pro but can open in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, arcgis-pro

I am trying to get a shapefile to show in ArcGIS Pro. I believe it's an issue with the projection. It is opening in QGIS but not ArcGIS Pro. When I move the point, line, or polygon layer into ArcGIS Pro, the base map turns white. This is true for QGIS too. I have tried using the Projection tool and the points are still not showing up. I am also able to open up the attribute table for these layers, but cannot see them. How can I get them to show up?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take  the [Tour]. ArcGIS doesn't honor a QGIS projection file -- it must be .prj in the appropriate format. The fact that basemaps turn white may be a separate issue. Please [Edit] the question to provide the contents of the `.prj` file, the sizes of the files you have tried (filesystem storage in bytes), and the envelope extent of each file.

Comment: @Sierra, please post your shapefile.